# Prove that D is strongly connected if and only if for every edge-cut S of the underlying graph G that separates V (G − S) into two sets A and B

Tags: graph-theory

I'm struggling with writing a detailed proof for this.

Let D be a digraph with at least two nodes, and let G be the underlying graph of D.

An edge-cut of G is a set S of edges of G such that G−S is disconnected, where G−S
denotes the graph obtained from G by deleting all edges in S.
Now,

Prove that D is strongly connected if and only if
for every edge-cut S of the underlying graph G of D that separates V (G − S) into two sets A and B,
there is an arc in D directed from a node in A to a node in B and an arc in D directed from a node
in B to a node in A.

So far, i have assumed D is strongly connected.
Taken u and v as two vertices in D, and since D is strongly connected both vertices are reachable from one another (path from u to v and a path from v to u).

Then an edge cut is performed on G, such that v and u are separated into two connected components, then v $\in$ A and u $\in$ B.
I know that the edges that are cut represent the path from u to v and from v to u, but don't know how to explain via a proof. Also how do i explain the only if part?

Answer (score 1):

For the forward part: Let $D$ be strongly connected connected, and let $S\subseteq E(G)$ be a cut inducing the components with vertex sets $A$ and $B$. Moreover, let $v\in A$ and $u\in B$. Since $D$ is strongly connected, there exists a directed path $P_{vu}$ from $v$ to $u$. Since $u$ and $v$ are in different components of $G-S$, $P_{uv}$ contains an edge in $S$. The argument is identical for proving there is an arc from $B$ to $A$. Since $S$, $a$ and $b$ were arbitrary, we are done.

Suppose now that for every edge-cut $S$ of $G$ of that separates $V (G − S)$ into two sets $A$ and $B$, there is an arc in $D$ directed from a node in $A$ to a node in $B$ and an arc in $D$ directed from a node in $B$ to a node in $A$. Consider any two vertices $u$ and $v$. We proceed by constructing a directed path from $v$ to $u$. Let $A_1 :=\{v\}$ and let $S_1$ be the set of outgoing edges from $v$, and let $B_1:= V(G)\setminus A_1$. By assumption, there is an edge $e=vv_1$ outgoing from $v$ to a vertex in $B_1$. If $v_1=u$ we are done, by adding $u$ to $A_1$ forming $A_2$, where $A_2$ contains a path from $v$ to $u$. Otherwise, iterate this process of adding vertices from $B_1$ to $A_1$ forming $A_2$ and $B_2$ and so on. By assumption, this can always be done, and eventually this iterative process stops when $v$ is added to $A_i$. At each step of this iteration, we only consider adding vertices which have an incoming edge from a vertex in $A_i$. Thus, there is a path from $v$ to the vertex added at step $i$. Thus, there is a path from $v$ to $u$.

Answer (score 0):

I also stumbled upon this problem and found a somewhat cleaner solution to this problem (which is a more detailed implementation of the previous answer).

Note: I'll use vertex to refer to node

First: Proving "If $D$ is strongly connected then for every edge-cut $S$ of the underlying graph $G$ of $D$ that separates $V(G − S)$ into two sets $A$ and $B$, there is an arc in $D$ directed from a vertex in $A$ to a vertex in $B$ and an arc in $D$ directed from a vertex in $B$ to a vertex in $A$"

We're given a digraph $D$ which is strongly connected.
Take $S_0$ an arbitrary edge-cut of the underlying graph $G$ of $D$. Then $S_0$ separates $V(G-S_0)$ into two sets $A_0$ and $B_0$. Next, take $a\in A_0$ and $b \in B_0$. Since $D$ is strongly connected, there exist an $a-b$ path and a $b-a$ path. This implies the existence of an arc in $D$ from $A_0$ to $B_0$ and and arc in $D$ from $B_0$ and $A_0$ (since the $a-b$ path must walk from $a$ in $A_0$ to $b$ in $B_0$, simply observe the two vertices inside the path in which the first vertex is in $A_0$ and it is directed to the second vertex in $B_0$). Since $a$, $b$, and $S_0$ are arbitrary our first prove is complete.

Second: Proving "If for every edge-cut $S$ of the underlying graph $G$ of $D$ that separates $V(G − S)$ into two sets $A$ and $B$, there is an arc in $D$ directed from a vertex in $A$ to a vertex in $B$ and an arc in $D$ directed from a vertex in $B$ to a vertex in $A$ then $D$ is strongly connected."

We're given that for every edge-cut $S$ of the underlying graph $G$ of $D$ that separates $V(G − S)$ into two sets $A$ and $B$, there is an arc in $D$ directed from a vertex in $A$ to a vertex in $B$ and an arc in $D$ directed from a vertex in $B$ to a vertex in $A$ then $D$.

Observe $S(V)$ which I define as the edge-cut to separate the vertices $V$ from the other vertex in the underlying graph $G$. Now say $W$ is the vertex set of the digraph $D$ where $W = \{w_1, w_2, \dots, w_n\}$. Next take an arbitrary $w_0 \in W$, and $S(W_0)$ where $W_0=\{w_0\}$. Then $S(W_0)$ separate graph $G$ into two sets $A$ and $B$. Take $A$ as the set which contains $w_0$ and $B$ the set which contains the other vertices. Then the premise guarantees an arc from $w_0$ in $A$ to a vertex $w_i$ in $B$. Add $w_i$ to $W_0$ making $W_1$ and continue observing $W_1$ anda $S(W_1)$. The premise guarantees an arc from a vertex in $W_1$ (in $A$) to another vertex $w_{i+1}$ outside $W_1$ (in $B$). This implies the existence of a path from $w_0$ to $w_{i+1}$ (either directly or via another vertex in $W_1$). Add $w_{i+1}$ to $W_1$ making $W_2$ and continue this procedure until every vertex in $W$ is in $W_{n-1}$

This procedure guarantees that there will always exist a path from $w_0$ to any other vertices in $W$. Note that this procedure only use the '*there is an arc in $D$ directed from a vertex in $A$ to a vertex in $B$*' part of the premise. Applying the '*there is an arc in $D$ directed from a vertex in $B$ to a vertex in $A$ then $D$*' part to the procedure guarantees that there will always exist a path from any other vertices in $W$ to $w_0$. Lastly, since $w_0$ is arbitrary, we can conclude that the digraph $D$ is strongly connected. (since every vertex $u$ and $v$ in $D$ has a $u-v$ path and $v-u$ path).

I didn't expect my answer to be this long, but I hope this would make it easier to understand the solution